# How to declare a cursor in PHPmyadmin MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cursors

I tried to simply declare a cursor, and it didn't work.

`DECLARE ICursor CURSOR FOR SELECT items.name, items.cost, items.bids FROM items`

I tried to do so inside a procedure, and it still doesn't work.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE create_cursor()
BEGIN
    DECLARE ICursor CURSOR FOR SELECT items.name, items.cost, items.bids FROM items;
OPEN ICursor;
FETCH FIRST FROM ICursor;
CLOSE ICursor;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I also tried declaring an empty variable before declaring the cursor, and still no go.

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "*doesn't work*" isn't an error message that I've ever encountered, though at a glance I can see that your cursor selects three columns but you're trying to fetch them into a single (undeclared) variable—and even if that worked, you're not doing anything with it thereafter, so you'd never be able to observe whether it "worked" or not.

Comment: The error I get is: "Unrecognized statement type. (near "DECLARE" at position 0)" - I'm not trying to define a variable but rather a cursor, and I try to follow the SQL syntax: DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR select_statement, basically trying to follow this tutorial over here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHRjLd0bEaQ, and other tutorials who seem to be able to declare a cursor...